# Como pegar a Geolocalização atual do celular usando React Native?

Tags: react, react-native, geolocalização

Estou tentando pegar a minha latitude e longitude, para isso utilizei o seguinte código:

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

export default function Map({ navigation }) {
    
    const [latitude, setLatitude]=useState(0)
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data=>{
        setLatitude(data.coords.latitude)
    });

    const [longitude, setLongitude]=useState(0)
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data=>{
        setLongitude(data.coords.longitude)
    });

    return (
        <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            region={{
                latitude: latitude,
                longitude: longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0042,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0031,
            }}
            style={styles.mapView}
            rotateEnabled={false}
        >
            <Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: latitude,
                    longitude: longitude
                }}
            />
        </MapView>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mapView: {
        flex: 1,
    }
})
```

Ele me retorna uma latitude e longitude, porém não são da minha posição atual, é de um outro local (outra cidade nos USA). Preciso da latitude e longitude para armazenar em um BD que já possuo.

Estou usando o Android Simulator e quando uso o Google Maps ele consegue a minha localização certinha.

PS: Já adicionei as permissões no Android Manifest.

Comment: Você consegue testar num dispositivo real? Isso tem chances de ser coisa do emulador (é só um palpite)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

const [CurrentRegion, setCurrentRegion] = useState(null);

async function loadInitialPosition(){
    await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            const {coords} = position
            const {latitude, longitude} = coords
            setCurrentRegion({
                latitude,
                longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0.005,
            })
        },
    );
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialPosition();
},[]);


function handleRegionChange(region) {
    console.log("regiao", region)
    setCurrentRegion(region);
}

if (!getCurrentRegion) {
    return null;
}


<MapsView
    onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChange}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    initialRegion={getCurrentRegion}
    showsUserLocation
    loadingEnabled
/>
```

Executa e me fala se funcionou.

Comment: Eu tentei aplicar aqui no meu app o seu código mas eu ainda estou um pouco perdido de como aplicar isso dentro do meu <MapView>

Comment: Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, eu já ajudei ele e descobrimos uns erros e já consertamos, mas foi bom você ter me dado esse alerta, na minha próxima resposta eu irei fazer umas anotações do que cada linha faz, assim qualquer um que entrar já saia com a resposta na mão